# Is there a way to prevent timeout of embedded create signer view in C#?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

[Current Docusign setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJJPp.png)

In the documentation, it says there is a Receipient Session Timeout session.  Attached is what we currently have on live.  After 20 minutes, it says your session will end due to inactivity.

Comment: maybe you should [contact sales](https://www.docusign.co.uk/contact-sales) they will now why you get a timeout ...

Answer (score 0):

There are two different timesout to consider with embedded signing:

1. URL expires after 5 min. This is so that the URL that was generated by the app is used right away and not shared to reduce security risk. You have to use the URL from your app quickly.
2. Signing inactivity.  20 min. This is to protect the end-user who may be on a device that can be used by others.

The screenshot you shared is actually neither of these. It's for the senders or users of the web app and it's similar inactivity to protect from that.

It's very important to have these timeouts as a security measure, so you cannot disable them.